# how to reflect changes by replacing class files in tomcat?

Tags: java, class, tomcat6

I have a java application. All I have with me is a set on class files. Iwant to replace one class file with a new one. Replacing the old class file with the new one and restrting tomcat is not reflecting the changes. How can I do this? I know its not a recommended way, but all I have is just one new class file.

Comment: If it doesn't "reflect changes" after restarting it ... you didn't make any changes. I suspect your webapp is in a `war` file and is getting redeployed on startup, overwriting anything you've done.

Comment: I had the same issue using an Eclipse Kepler Dynamic Web project and Tomcat 7.0 as a workspace server.  I fixed it by resolving all the project's problems, then, by right-clicking the Tomcat server, selected Clean, then Publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this the way you describe before, and Tomcat reflected the changes just fine after restart.

Perhaps your application's files are in multiple locations, and you aren't replacing the class file in the correct deployment?  Make sure if Tomcat is auto-expanding the WAR that you are replacing it in the expanded folder of files.  If you app is deployed somewhere besides `webapps`, double-check where your `<Context>` is pointing to for its doc base.

Comment: how do I avoid redeploying of the war file on tomcat stratup?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think if Tomcat finds a folder with the same name as the WAR, it will assume that folder is the expanded WAR, and won't redeploy.  Let's say you have `tomcat/webapps/myApp.war`, and an expanded folder `tomcat/webapps/myApp`.  You should be able to replace your `.class` file in `tomcat/webapps/myApp/WEB-INF/classes/path/to/file.class`, and Tomcat should pick those changes up on restart.  I've done this many times and it works the way you expect it to, so you must either be replacing the wrong file, or however you are verifying the changes is incorrect.

Comment: I just double checked this. I have the correct file replaced in the correct location. but tomcat is not picking it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Tomcat and make your webapp "reloadable". To do so, add `reloadable=true` to the `<Context>` element of your webapp.

Set to `true` if you want Catalina to monitor classes in `/WEB-INF/classes/` and `/WEB-INF/lib` for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected.  You can use the [Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html) web application, however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand.

Comment: This reloads the whole application, anyway to just swap-in that particular class file only?